# Jenkins Allure does not generate valid links based on @issue

Tags: jenkins, properties, cucumber, allure

I have my .featue file which contains at the beginning the annotation `@issue=JIRA-123`. Afer I run the cucumber Selenium script I get my json outputs. These output contains the following part: `"links":[{"name":"JIRA-123","type":"issue"}],`

Allure does create a valid report with the issue, but the link does not work correctly. 
The following properties had been set in my jenkins. I guess they are correct.
[image: Jenkins Allure Properties]

Allure generates the following report and sets the given link for the issue. 
The link points directly to the dashboard of the test. What must I change in order to get a valid link in the issue section of the report?

[image: Allure Report]

Comment: what adaptor version are you using?

Comment: @DmitryBaev I use Jenkins plugin version 2.26.0

Comment: I mean what version of allure-cucumber

Comment: I use allure-cucumber2-jvm in version 2.6.0